# Protect Private Data in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, private, amazon-cloudfront

I want to upload some images on Amazon S3 and based on the user's subscription give them the access of viewing some portions of these images. After reading Amazon S3 documentation I have come up with these solutions:

1. Assigning each user in my application to one IAM user in Amazon S3 and then defining user policy or bucket policy to manage who has access to what. But there is two drawbacks: First, the user or bucket policies have limit on their size and since the number of users and images are very large it is very likely that I need to exceed that limit. Second, the number of IAM users per AWS account is bounded to 5000 and I would have more users in my application.
2. Amazon S3 makes it possible to define some temporary security credentials that act the same as IAM users. It's possible for me to require the client side to make a request to my server and I create a temporary IAM user for them with a special policy and pass them their credentials then they can directly send request to S3 using their credentials and have access to their resources. But the problem is that these users would last between 15 min to 1 hour and therefore the clients need to request my server at least every 1 hour to make a temporary IAM user for them.
3. Since I want to serve some images it is a good practice to use combination of Amazon Cloudfront and S3 to serve the content as quick as possible. I have also read the Cloudfront documentation for serving private content and I found out that their solution is using signed URLs or signed cookies. I will deny any access to S3 resources and the cloudfront would be the only one who has the access to read data from S3 and every time a user signs in to my application I would send them the credentials that they need to have to make a signed URL or I would send them the necessary cookies. They can request required resources with the information that they have and this information would last until they are signed in to my application. But I have some security concerns. Since almost all of the information about access control is sent to the client (e.g. in cookies) they can easily modify it and grant themselves more permissions. However it is a big concern but I think I have to use cloudfront for decreasing loading resource time.

I want to know you think which of these solutions is more reasonable and better than others and also if there are other solutions maybe using other Amazon web services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own approach to serve private content on S3 is by using CloudFront with either **signed URLs** or **signed cookies** (or sometimes, both). You *should not* use IAM users or temporary credentials for large number of users, as in your case.

You can read more about this topic here:
[Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Your choice of whether to use signed URLs or signed cookies depends on the following.

> [Choosing Between Signed URLs and Signed Cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html)
>
> CloudFront signed URLs and signed cookies provide the same basic
>   functionality: they allow you to control who can access your content.
>   If you want to serve private content through CloudFront and you're
>   trying to decide whether to use signed URLs or signed cookies,
>   consider the following.
>
> Use signed URLs in the following cases:
>
> - You want to use an RTMP distribution. Signed cookies aren't supported
>     for RTMP distributions.
> - You want to restrict access to individual files, for example, an installation download for your application.
> - Your users are using a client (for example, a custom HTTP client) that
>     doesn't support cookies.
>
> Use signed cookies in the following cases:
>
> - You want to provide access to multiple restricted files, for example,
>     all of the files for a video in HLS format or all of the files in the
>     subscribers' area of a website.
> - You don't want to change your current
>     URLs.

As for your security concerns, CloudFront uses the public key to validate the signature in the signed cookie and to confirm that the cookie hasn't been tampered with. If the signature is invalid, the request is rejected.

You can also follow the guidelines at the end of [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) to prevent misuse of signed cookies.

Comment: So how do manage the security concerns? The users who have the cookie can misuse it to have none-granted access to the resources on S3

Comment: @user3070752: Signed cookies are secure. End users cannot modify the cookies without invalidating them. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not very familiar with public-private key security methods. If I send the private key to the end user with the desired custom policy (even if the policy is hashed but maybe they are able to somehow retrieve the original policy and change it for instance change resource key in policy), then how does cloudfront public key would make sure that the users have not modified the cookie. Actually after reading Cloudfront documentation it is still unclear for me that how does cloudfront make sure that the end user could not misuse the information they have.

Comment: Indeed, I think we don't save any information in cloudfront that who has access to what so it would be easy for end users to change their access to resources. Maybe I'm missing something important with this approach.

Comment: @user3070752: You don't send the private key to the user. You use the private key to generate the signed cookie in your preferred SDK and CloudFront checks the integrity of the signed cookie using the public key whenever the client tries to access the restricted content. Then, it checks other attributes such as expiry date and access policy.

Comment: So when a user logs in to our application we send him a signed cookie. This process so far has nothing to do with CloudFront. Then, the end user uses this signed cookie to get restricted content in CloudFront. The CloudFront would use the information in the cookie (i.e. key-pair ID) to validate the received request and if valid serve the content. Well, if an end user could somehow retrieve the information in the cookie that we have used to create the signed cookie (e.g. the private key and others) then they can themselves make a valid cookie and get private content.

Comment: So all of the security lays in the inability of end users to extract the information that have been used to create the cookie from the cookie that they have. Am I right?

Comment: @user3070752: Generating the signed cookie is actually part of the CloudFront SDK (`AmazonCloudFrontCookieSigner` utility class). The client CANNOT possibly use the information retrieved from the signed cookie to generate a new signed cookie because this information simply does not contain the private key. This is how public key cryptography works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography